# Material UI breakpoints to set orientation: portrait and landscape view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, responsive

Would like to be able to set portrait and landscape views on the styles object for tablets in Material UI

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
    }
  }
}
```

how can i add breakpoints for portrait view and landscape view similar to the traditional media query:

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Comment: what issue you're facing ?

Answer (score 10):

Just set something like that:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit,
    [`${theme.breakpoints.up('md')} and (orientation: portrait)`]: {
      flexDirection: 'column'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're able to use something like this:

```
'@media (orientation: landscape)': {
  flexDirection: `orientation`,
},
```

for the component media query will be attached.

Comment: Only remember that this rule, should go as a separate element but not as a nested.

Answer (score 0):

#### Used this in version 4.11.1

```js
const useStyles = makeStyle((theme) =>({
    container:{
        border:"1px dashed red",
        [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]{
           border: "1px solid blue",
           '@media (orientation: landscape)': {
              border: "1px solid green",,
            },
        },
    },
}));
```